# Why does this if statement always run?

Tags: php, mysql

```
  if ($unitWeight != 0) 
  {
    $saleableUnits = ($sumQty/$unitWeight);
    $unitCost      = ($sumCost/$saleableUnits);
  }
```

I'm expecting this statement to run only if $unitWeight is greater than 0. It seems to run no matter what and I get this error.

"Warning: Division by zero in"

Comment: try `intval($unitWeight) != 0`

Comment: because you say if `$unitWeight` is not 0 do this code so for example -1 and the code runs

Comment: You can still get division by zero if `$saleableUnits == 0`. Always check for zero before dividing.

Comment: @user4035 ah yes. Saleableunits was = 0 so the second line was where error came from. Working fine with this        if ($unitWeight > 0) {
  $saleableUnits = ($sumQty/$unitWeight);
  }
  
  if($saleableUnits > 0) {
  $unitCost      = ($sumCost/$saleableUnits);
  }

Answer (score 2):

Try typecasting the your variable

```
$unitWeight = (int) "0";

var_dump(($unitWeight));
```

Or use `abs()` or `intval()`

```
$unitWeight = "0";

var_dump(abs($unitWeight));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use greater than ( > )

```
if ($unitWeight > 0) 
  {
    $saleableUnits = ($sumQty/$unitWeight);
    $unitCost      = ($sumCost/$saleableUnits);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use method **empty()** for checking code like this because **empty()** also check is the `$unitWeight` are set somewhere

```
if ( !empty($unitWeight) ){

    $saleableUnits = ($sumQty/$unitWeight);
    $unitCost      = ($sumCost/$saleableUnits);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the statement to run only if `$unitWeight` is > 0, then that is what you should use.

See below:

```
  if (intval($unitWeight) > 0){
    $saleableUnits = ($sumQty/$unitWeight);
    $unitCost      = ($sumCost/$saleableUnits);
  }
```

Use intval() to get `intval — Get the integer value of a variable` as described in the official documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Please keep in mind, it is always beneficial and imperative that you sanitize your input and ensure that only numeric values are accepted.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer try using

```
if ($unitWeight > 0){
    $saleableUnits = ($sumQty/$unitWeight);
    $unitCost      = ($sumCost/$saleableUnits);
}
```

And the big thing is may be already the `$unitWeight` must be greater than `0` i think, that's why it is always going inside the if condition.

before the if condition try printing the value of `$unitWeight` variable, so that you can find what is inside the variable and also the reason why it gets inside the condition.

Then finally like same print the variables `$sumQty` and `$sumCost`.

might be any of these variable have a value of `0` that is why it is showing the error you have mentioned